# Prove that X = Y

Tags: functions

Let $X=\{n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n \;|\, n \geq 0\}$ and $Y=\{n^3 - 1 \;|\, n > 0\}$. Prove that $X=Y$.

I solve this question by putting $n=0$ in $X$
So, $x= 0+0+0 = 0$
and I put $n=1$ in $Y$
and so: $1-1=0$.
Therefore, $X=Y$

I do not know if my answer correct or wrong.

Could someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To do this, you have to show that *every* element of one set is a member of the other set, in both directions, i.e. that $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$. I'll show one direction and you can do the other:

Let's show $X \subseteq Y$. Suppose $x \in X$. Then $x = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n$ for some $n \ge 0$. But note that $(n + 1)^3 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1$, so we have $x = (n + 1)^3 - 1$. Now since $n \ge 0$, $(n + 1) > 0$, so $x \in Y$. Thus $X \subseteq Y$.

Now, show $Y \subseteq X$.

Comment: in line 4, why you add n+1?

Comment: Well, we have $(n+1)^3 - 1 = (n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n + 1) - 1 = n^3 + 3n^2 + 3n$. Is that what you're looking for? Or why do you use the identity given? Because that matches the pattern in the defining polynomial for $n$. I'm not quite clear what you mean by "add".

Comment: Now I understand, thanks my friend

Comment: @user3634358: You're most welcome.